# Improving performance of updating large table with join

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-update, large-data

Currently I have a table with schema as follows:

```
 mData | CREATE TABLE `mData` (
   `m1` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `m2` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `m3` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `m4` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `m5` date DEFAULT NULL,
   KEY `m_m1` (`m1`) USING HASH,
   KEY `m_date` (`m5`),
   KEY `m_m2` (`m2`),
   KEY `m_combined` (`m1`,`m2`,`m5`),
   KEY `m1_tradeday` (`m1`,`m5`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
 /*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE ( YEAR(m5))
 SUBPARTITION BY HASH (MONTH(m5))
 (PARTITION p2013 VALUES LESS THAN (2014)
  (SUBPARTITION dec_2013 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jan_2013 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION feb_2013 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION mar_2013 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION apr_2013 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION may_2013 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jun_2013 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jul_2013 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION aug_2013 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION sep_2013 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION oct_2013 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION nov_2013 ENGINE = InnoDB),
  PARTITION p2014 VALUES LESS THAN (2015)
  (SUBPARTITION dec_2014 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jan_2014 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION feb_2014 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION mar_2014 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION apr_2014 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION may_2014 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jun_2014 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jul_2014 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION aug_2014 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION sep_2014 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION oct_2014 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION nov_2014 ENGINE = InnoDB),
  PARTITION p2015 VALUES LESS THAN (2016)
  (SUBPARTITION dec_2015 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jan_2015 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION feb_2015 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION mar_2015 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION apr_2015 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION may_2015 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jun_2015 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jul_2015 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION aug_2015 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION sep_2015 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION oct_2015 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION nov_2015 ENGINE = InnoDB),
  PARTITION p2016 VALUES LESS THAN (2017)
  (SUBPARTITION dec_2016 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jan_2016 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION feb_2016 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION mar_2016 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION apr_2016 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION may_2016 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jun_2016 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jul_2016 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION aug_2016 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION sep_2016 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION oct_2016 ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION nov_2016 ENGINE = InnoDB),
  PARTITION pmax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
  (SUBPARTITION dec_max ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jan_max ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION feb_max ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION mar_max ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION apr_max ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION may_max ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jun_max ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION jul_max ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION aug_max ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION sep_max ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION oct_max ENGINE = InnoDB,
   SUBPARTITION nov_max ENGINE = InnoDB)) */ |
```

m1, m2, and m5 are set as index in this table, unique/primary are not applicable in my case.

As the data is getting bigger (100,000 new row a day), the update command is getting very slow.

I would like to know if there are any ways to improve the following statement.

```
update mData as a join (select * from mData
                        where m1 = 326 and m5 = '2015-   07-06' ) as b
            on  a.m5 > b.m5 and a.m1 = b.m1
            and a.m2 = b.m2 and a.m3 = b.m3
    set a.m4 = 0;
```

I am quite sure that in select statement, if I replace `mData as a` to `(select * from mData  where m1 = 326)`, the executive time could largely reduce (from 5 sec to less than 1 sec).

However, it is not possible to do the same in `UPDATE` statement.

Is there any solution for this, to speed up update?

P.S. the table has been partitioned by month(m5) and year(m5)

Here is the EXPLAIN partitions for my join query, very messy, hope you don't mind. Adding ' and a.m5 > '2015-07-06' does improve the perfomance, query time drops from 0.68 sec to 0.2 sec.

```
explain partitions (select * from (select * from mData where m1 = 326) as a join (select * from mData where m1 = 326 and m5= '2015-07-06') as b on  a.m5 > b.m5 and a.m1 = b.m1 and a.m2 = b.m2 and a.m3 = b.m3 and a.m5 > '2015-07-06');
```

| id | select_type | table      | partitions                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | type | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                                 | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+----+-------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             ------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             +
|  1 | PRIMARY     |  | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       | ALL  | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |  358 |                                                                                                                                                                                             |
|  1 | PRIMARY     |  | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       | ALL  | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL | 1073 | Using where; Using join buffer                                                                                                                                                              |
|  3 | DERIVED     | mData | p2015_jul_2015                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | ref  | m_m1,m_m5,m_combined,m1_m5                                                                                                                                                              | m1_m5 | 8       |      |  357 | Using where                                                                                                                                                                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | mData | p2013_dec_2013,p2013_jan_2013,p2013_feb_2013,p                                                                                                                                                             2013_mar_2013,p2013_apr_2013,p2013_may_2013,p2013_jun_2013,p2013_jul_2013,p2013_                                                                                                                                                             aug_2013,p2013_sep_2013,p2013_oct_2013,p2013_nov_2013,p2014_dec_2014,p2014_jan_2                                                                                                                                                             014,p2014_feb_2014,p2014_mar_2014,p2014_apr_2014,p2014_may_2014,p2014_jun_2014,p                                                                                                                                                             2014_jul_2014,p2014_aug_2014,p2014_sep_2014,p2014_oct_2014,p2014_nov_2014,p2015_                                                                                                                                                             dec_2015,p2015_jan_2015,p2015_feb_2015,p2015_mar_2015,p2015_apr_2015,p2015_may_2                                                                                                                                                             015,p2015_jun_2015,p2015_jul_2015,p2015_aug_2015,p2015_sep_2015,p2015_oct_2015,p                                                                                                                                                             2015_nov_2015,p2016_dec_2016,p2016_jan_2016,p2016_feb_2016,p2016_mar_2016,p2016_                                                                                                                                                             apr_2016,p2016_may_2016,p2016_jun_2016,p2016_jul_2016,p2016_aug_2016,p2016_sep_2                                                                                                                                                             016,p2016_oct_2016,p2016_nov_2016,pmax_dec_max,pmax_jan_max,pmax_feb_max,pmax_ma                                                                                                                                                             r_max,pmax_apr_max,pmax_may_max,pmax_jun_max,pmax_jul_max,pmax_aug_max,pmax_sep_                                                                                                                                                             max,pmax_oct_max,pmax_nov_max | ref  | m_m1,m_combined,m1_m5                                                                                                                                                                         | m_m1    | 4       |      | 1074 | Using where                                                                                                                                                                                 |

Below is the query explain asked by "Rick James"

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS select * from ccass_data where sid = 326 and trade_day = '2015-07-06';

| id | select_type | table      | partitions     | type | possible_keys                                    | key          | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
 +----+-------------+------------+----------------+------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | mData     | p2015_jul_2015 | ref  | m_m1,m_m5,m_combined,m1_m5               | m1_m5 | 8    | const,const |  357    | Using where        |
```

Comment: Why is it not possible to add `where m1 = 326` to the update statement? Also, do you have a composite index on `m1,m2,m3`?

Comment: Because  this  does not make improvement. It is the  join between a full table and its sub query which takes most of the execution. Adding where make no difference.

Comment: For the composite index, is it going to speed up a lot? Thanks so much on your advice.

Comment: If you have a composite index on `m1,m2,m5` the join is using the first 2 parts of it at the moment. It should get faster if there is an index on all 3, but I can't predict how much faster.

Comment: I hv tried the composite index of m1, m2 and m5, still the same

Comment: Please provide us with the `PARTITION BY ...` part of the `CREATE TABLE`; something does no make sense.

Comment: Don't create future partitions until you need them.  Instead, have one `future` partition that will catch data in case you fail to `REORGANIZE PARTITIONS` on time.  More discussion in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Comment: Please show us the indexes, too.  Better yet, add the entire `CREATE TABLE mData;` to your Question.

Comment: James, your blog has provided a lot of useful experience on MySQL, it's really great. Does  most of the rules still hold for those recent generation of MySQL ?

Comment: All (or nearly all) of the blog applies to all versions of MySQL, at least through 5.6.  5.7.6 introduced "native partitioning", which will change a few things, but is mostly a re-implementation of partitioning (InnoDB only).  I update my blogs as I see the need.  If you can demonstrate some benefit from your use of `SUBPARTITION` and/or `HASH`, I would love to add it to my blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, add `INDEX(m1, m5)`.  After I see `SHOW CREATE TABLE mData;`, I may have other recommendations.

**EDIT**

Adding `AND a.m5 > '2015-07-06'` *may* get partition pruning to kick in.  I don't have any experience with `UPDATE` and `SUBPARTITION` to predict.

InnoDB *must* have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  Would `(m1, m2, m3, m5)` work as a PK?

`USING HASH` is ignored, since InnoDB does not implement it.  It will be a BTree, which is nearly as good, anyway.

```
KEY `m_m1` (`m1`)
```

is redundant and can be dropped, since there is another (actually two) index that *starts* with it.

Can't you do a `JOIN` instead of using a subquery?  (That would avoid a tmp table.)

Comment: Hi, james, I added the index(m1, m5) before. I have updated the post with show create table, please check, many thanks.

Comment: How many partitions do you get from `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS select * from mData  where m1 = 326 and m5 = '2015-   07-06';` ?

Comment: 1. does the redundant index slow down the query, actually, what should be the best rule for adding index?

2. m1, m2, m5 together could form a primary key, but does it slow the table if I add another primary key e.g. id for the table? since there is about 100,000 per day for my table

3. I have tried, a join between a large table is very slow

I have updated my post with the query you proposed to test

Comment: Redundant indexes slow down INSERT some.  They waste disk space.  In an obtuse way, they can slow down SELECTs.

Comment: There can be no more than one PRIMARY KEY in a table.  InnoDB fabricates a hidden one if you don't provide one.  Adding a PK will replace that fabricated one.

Comment: Good.  I was not sure the subquery would hit one subpartition (it did).  So the long list of partitions (all of them?) in the original EXPLAIN is from the outer SELECT.  Adding the AND that I suggested will probably shrink the list some.

Comment: Adding ' and a.m5 > '2015-07-06' does improve the perfomance, query time drops from 0.68 sec to 0.2 sec. why's that? but the list seems the same in terms of length. I have update the explain too. To the long list partition question. yes, that's all of them.

Comment: The improved speed might be caching; it might be less work needed.  The failure to prune could be a deficiency in `UPDATE` or use of `HASH` or something else.  (I have yet to find _any_ usefulness for "HASH" partitioning.)

Answer (score 0):

First I would use the fixed value for m5 in order to limit the partitions to consider. Maybe you should add also a dummy condition on year(m5) and month(m5). 
Then I would create a temp table for the subquery and an index on m2 and m3. Then I'd use the fixed values for m1 and m5. 
But how many times the query is executed? 5 secs is not a terrible result.

Comment: Do u mean something like primary id for each record? Because when i use join on two sub query, it only takes less than 1 sec, i feel that it could be faster but update statement only allows one sub query

Comment: I would try replace the update query with a store procedure. In the store procedure I would:
1. create a temp table with the result of the inner query
2. create an index on the temp table on the m2 and m3 fields
3. update the table joining with the temp table
Makes sense?

Comment: Seems not. The problem lies in the slow joining using the full table, the table would take a long to finish any join operation unless it is trimmed down

Comment: Can you publish the query plan? It sounds like it's not using properly the partitions.

Comment: Do you mean using EXPLAIN in MySQL? Please excuse my ignorance on the professional terms. I am not a professional in SQL. :P

Comment: I have updated my post and added the explain partitions. Thank @cristian